# Is it possible to increase the limit of 20 Instagram posts displayed on your own website?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to increase the set limit of 20 posts when embedding Instagram on your own website. Instagram won't allow app submission if you are just displaying your own content on your own website and the sandbox is limited to 20 items. Does anyone know of a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look at this library: https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper

It allows scrape public info without auth.

```
$medias = Instagram::getMedias('kevin', 200);
```